# Finite quotients of $p$-adic congruence subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}_2$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, profinite-groups, p-adic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $  \SL^1_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ denote the kernel of the natrual surjective morphism $\SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)\rightarrow \SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p/p\mathbb{Z}_p)$. Then the abelianization of $\SL^1_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^3$. Recall that there are only two nonabelian groups with order $p^3$ up to isomorphism as follows:

1. $G_1=\langle x,y\mid x^{p^2}=y^p=1,~y^{-1}xy=x^{1+p}\rangle$.
2. $G_2=\langle x,y,z\mid x^p=y^p=z^p=1,~xz=zx,~zy=yz,~xy=yxz\rangle$.

**Question:** Is there a continuous surjective morphism $\SL^1_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)\to G_i$ for $i=1,2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbf{Z}}$Indeed, $G_1$ is a quotient, but not $G_2$.

First, one checks that the third term in the lower central series is the kernel of $\SL_2^1(\Z_p)\to\SL_2^1(\Z/p^3\Z)$. So this converts this into a question about quotients of a group of order $p^6$, namely $\SL_2^1(\Z/p^3\Z)$.

For this group, the derived subgroup is central and generated by $p$-powers. This already implies that every quotient of $\SL_2^1(\Z/p^3\Z)$ of exponent $p$ is abelian, and hence $G_2$ is not a quotient.

One gets $G_1$ by modding out by the normal subgroup of elements of the form $\begin{pmatrix}1+p^2a & 0\\ pc & 1-p^2a\end{pmatrix}$ for $a\in\Z/p\Z$, $c\in\Z/p^2\Z$.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbf{Z}}$Just curious. Is the wreath product $(\Z/p\Z) \wr (\Z/p\Z)$ also the quotient of $\SL_2^1(\Z_p)$?

Comment: @stupidboy modding out by $p^2$-powers kills $\mathrm{SL}^3_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$, and the quotient has order $p^6$ and abelianization of order $p^3$. This discards $p\ge 5$, I haven't checked $p=3$.